# Problem adding programmed Layout into my adapter

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, custom-view, android-custom-view

Here is my adapter

```
     private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 5;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView text=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            text.setText("SAmple text");
            Button button =(Button)new Button(MainActivity.this);
            button.setText("Click me");
            EditText edit=new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            ImageView image=new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            CheckBox check=new CheckBox(MainActivity.this);
            ToggleButton toggle=new ToggleButton(getApplicationContext());

            check.setChecked(true);
            layout.addView(check);
        layout.addView(toggle);




            if(position==0){
                convertView=text;

                }
            else if( position==1){
                convertView= button;
            }       
            else if(position==2){
                convertView= edit;
            }
            else if (position==3) {
                RelativeLayout rel=new View1(MainActivity.this);
                convertView=rel;
                }
            else{
                convertView=layout;
            }
            return convertView;
        }
```

And here is my custom view

```
package org.example.demo;



import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class View1 extends RelativeLayout{


    public View1(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setView(context);
    }

    public void setView(Context context){
        CheckBox check=new CheckBox(context);
        ToggleButton toggle=new ToggleButton(context);
        addView(check);
        addView(toggle);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Here is what I get
[image]

The problem is I can't get the view that I created outside of the adapter. Isn't it the same thing to create a view or viewgroup inside adapter or reference it to the outside? Or do I miss something overridding Layout methods?

Comment: ok I solved it

I just added this to onLayout method

        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);